# How to rewrite URL back to default custom URL if no destination found

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

**My current situation is:**

I'm redirecting the custom category request to below kind of url:

`http://my_url/news/category/abc`

I've managed to add my custom query var `category` and can get the query var now. The hook is as below:

```
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', function ($rules) {
    return
        ['^news/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=news&page=1&category=all'] +
        ['^news/category/(.+)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=news&category=$matches[1]'] +
        $rules;
});
```

Url like `http://my_url/news/category/abc` now goes to `archive-news.php` and list all posts which has custom category *abc*.

And url like `http://my_url/news/lalala` goes to `single-news.php` and display full content of post with title *lalala*.

**My problem is:**

when url is `http://my_url/news/category/` it goes to an empty page which I believe is t he `404.php`.

**Seek solution**

I'm think about how to redirect it to `http://my_url/news` in my hook so it will automatically picks *all* as its default category.

All practical solutions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "redirect it to `http://my_url/news`" - a standard redirect will change the URL in the browser's address bar, so, how about adding a rewrite rule for `/news/category/`, using the same rewrite rule for `/news/`, i.e. replace the `'^news/?$' =>` with `'^news(/category)?/?$' =>`.

Comment: I tried and it works! Thanks for your advice. All credits to you.